# Output of Spark DenseVector cast as StringType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What are the extra values in the output of DenseVector when cast as StringType?

The following should be reproducible.

```python
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.version

# u'2.2.0.cloudera1'

from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
import pyspark.sql.types as T

testdf = spark.createDataFrame([\
            (DenseVector([2, 3]),),\
            (DenseVector([4, 5]),),\
            (DenseVector([6, 7]),)],\
            ['DenseVectors'])

testdf \
  .withColumn('DenseVector as String', F.col('DenseVectors')
  .cast(T.StringType())) \
  .show(truncate=False)

#+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
#|DenseVectors|DenseVector as String                                     |
#+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
#|[2.0,3.0]   |[6,1,0,0,2800000020,2,0,4000000000000000,4008000000000000]|
#|[4.0,5.0]   |[6,1,0,0,2800000020,2,0,4010000000000000,4014000000000000]|
#|[6.0,7.0]   |[6,1,0,0,2800000020,2,0,4018000000000000,401c000000000000]|
#+------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not extra values. Vectors are implemented as `UserDefinedType` (`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT` / `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT` - with Spark 2 you should normally use that latter one) and don't have useful casting implementation (it would be nice to have one, so maybe you can open a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa) if there isn't one).

What you see is just a reflection of internal structure which contains:

- type encoded as byte.
- length if vector is sparse.
- indices vector if vector is sparse.
- values vector.

and is not designed to be human readable.

To get readable output use `udf`

```
@F.udf
def to_string(v):
    return str(v)

testdf.select(to_string("DenseVectors")).show()
# +-----------------------+
# |to_string(DenseVectors)|
# +-----------------------+
# |              [2.0,3.0]|
# |              [4.0,5.0]|
# |              [6.0,7.0]|
# +-----------------------+
```